# Load SCSS file dynamically on button click

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, sass

[image: different CSS files]

as you can see I have a scss file loaded for the entire project and I'd like to know if it is possible to change what scss file is loaded on the click of the button. keep  in mind this scss file applies on the root component but I'm going to place the button on a component that's it's grand-child.

I've tried a couple things along things but the problem is apparently there's no way to attribute a scss file other than by an import ( This is in /Components/App.jsx ) :

```
import '../scss/app.scss';
//import '../scss/darcula.scss'; for dark theme.
```

and if I uncomment the above the imported scss is darcula but I have no way to dynamically change the import set that I know of.

an acceptable solution would be a triggered seperate import that happens within the child which does not entirely replace the other file but instead only supersedes each redefined style allowing me to only change the collors to obtain this "night mode" button that I want.

I don't understand why requires can't be isolated inside ifs
Even if I do this :

```
turnLightsOnOff() {
    if (this.state.theme) {
        require('../../../scss/app.scss');
        this.setState({
            theme: false,
        });
    } else {
        //require('../../../scss/darcula.scss');
        this.setState({
            theme: true,
        });
    }
}
```

app.css is loaded even thought the condition for that if is not yet met

and if I uncomment the other line both scss are loaded one one top of another.

Comment: Don't know how you can achieve that but just a simple suggestion; Why don't you just use className for theme your app? Something like `<App className={this.props.theme} />`

Comment: I don't understand I'm using almost exclusively className over id. is there a special className functionality other than giving a div a .class that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear with my comment. I was trying to explain some implementation like this `body.black-theme h1 { color: '#F2F2F2' } body.white-theme h1 { color: '#606060' }`. this way changing the class name for body can change the entire apps theme. This was a small example to explain my solution. Might not work for you.

Comment: could you put is as a broader example with exact example of implementation as an answer please? being a beginner I don't quite yet see what this would look like :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCSS needs to be compiled at build time. Browsers do not have the ability to process SASS. In adition the require() method is a webpack method run at buildtime and not dynamically in the browser. What you could do is create splits with webpack utilizing something like [extract-css-chunks plugin](https://github.com/faceyspacey/extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin)

Comment: thats looks cool but pretty heavy-handed for something I though was going to be simple. I'm looking into it trying out the demo. do you really recommend this? As an Aside : native SASS support on browsers seems to me like a real necessary update.

Comment: it works phenomenally it's just way overkill don't you think?

Comment: Well, it doesn't add any weight to your finalized bundle, the plugin only exists on your local machine/build server. It does make installation take a little longer for any developer touching your code, but it reduces the size of the bundle that the client has to download by having two separate css files instead of one large one. SASS will likely go away now that CSS variables and modules are landing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Answer (score 3):

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31225646/2315280) for detail on theme managing. What I'm suggesting is the simpler solution (in my opinion)

Rather than seperating files with different styles like this;

```
/* main.css */
#box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

/* theme1.css */
#box {
    backround-color: red;
}

/* theme2.css */
#box {
    background-color: maroon
}
```

Setting them in a single file like this;

```
#box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

div.theme1 #box {
    backround-color: red;
}

div.theme2 #box {
    background-color: maroon
}
```

I know this is a css solution rather than scss but the logic is pretty much the same.

You can set the desired theme className on a higher level component and effect whole app.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.theme}>
                <MainApp />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Update**

You can do conditional require according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44650758/2315280).

```
class Main extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
         if(this.props.language === 'ar') {
            require('arabic.css');
         } else {
            require('english.css');
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I like the solution of having a separate file more because my reactjs app is made up of 50+ components all depending on that one scss file for their colors so if i have to go into each component and each div and set dynamic classes there it's wayy too much work

Comment: Updated answer. Please check the added part.

Comment: Ok that just loads both it seems as though react doesn't care if a css is mentioned within an if or not if it's mentioned somewhere it's loaded.